# Error initializing struts application on Tomcat 8.0

Tags: java, tomcat, struts

That's the error I get while trying to run my Struts application on Tomcat 8.0.

I configured my application using the basic process with Dynamic web project after that I included the Struts library on the application build path, and in web deployment assembly.

This is my **web.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>Struts(XML Based)</display-name>
        <!-- Declaration of the Struts 2 filter.  Since our entire web application will be a Struts 2
                    application, we will not have any other servlets or filters.  Of course, real Struts 2 
                    applications may also have other servlets or filters, but since we are doing only Struts 2
                    stuff in this example, we need only define the Struts 2 filter.  -->

    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>
   </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Here is the exception and stack trace:

> java.util.concurrent.executionexception:
>   org.apache.catalina.lifecycleexception: failed to start component
>   [standardengine[catalina].standardhost[localhost].standardcontext[/struts]]
>   at java.util.concurrent.futuretask.report(unknown source) at
>   java.util.concurrent.futuretask.get(unknown source) at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.containerbase.startinternal(containerbase.java:945)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.standardhost.startinternal(standardhost.java:871)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.lifecyclebase.start(lifecyclebase.java:145)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.containerbase$startchild.call(containerbase.java:1410)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.containerbase$startchild.call(containerbase.java:1400)
>   at java.util.concurrent.futuretask.run(unknown source) at
>   java.util.concurrent.threadpoolexecutor.runworker(unknown source) at
>   java.util.concurrent.threadpoolexecutor$worker.run(unknown source) at
>   java.lang.thread.run(unknown source) caused by:
>   org.apache.catalina.lifecycleexception: failed to start component
>   [standardengine[catalina].standardhost[localhost].standardcontext[/struts]]
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.lifecyclebase.start(lifecyclebase.java:162)
>   ... 6 more caused by: java.lang.noclassdeffounderror:
>   lcom/opensymphony/xwork2/util/logging/logger; at
>   java.lang.class.getdeclaredfields0(native method) at
>   java.lang.class.privategetdeclaredfields(unknown source) at
>   java.lang.class.getdeclaredfields(unknown source) at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.introspection.getdeclaredfields(introspection.java:106)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.webannotationset.loadfieldsannotation(webannotationset.java:267)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.webannotationset.loadapplicationfilterannotations(webannotationset.java:107)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.webannotationset.loadapplicationannotations(webannotationset.java:66)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.contextconfig.applicationannotationsconfig(contextconfig.java:336)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.contextconfig.configurestart(contextconfig.java:776)
>   at org.apache.catalina.startup.conte

Comment: Your question is lacking of details. What have you tried so far? What technologies/languages are you using? What you did specifically to cause this? Edit your question and add these detaials.
 https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: `java.lang.noclassdeffounderror: lcom/opensymphony/xwork2/util/logging/logger;`. Looks like you're missing dependencies.

Comment: Thanks to all off you. First of all the problem was the xwork jar version. I changed the jar to xwork-core2.2.3.jar and everything is working properly.